# Ubuntu wake-on-lan for Dell 4550?

Tags: ubuntu, dell, wake-on-lan

I'm asking this question on behalf of a friend.  I don't have access to this hardware, but I can contact my friend to get more info as required.

Does anyone know how to get wake-on-lan to work on a Dell 4550 with any recent version of Ubuntu?  My friend saw on the Ubuntu discussion forums that someone had wake-on-lan working with Ubuntu 8.04, but he hasn't seen anything newer than that.

Here is his statement:

> I inherited a 4550 (my gamer son got a
>   newer machine) and I can't get WOL to
>   work with Ubuntu 9.04 or 9.10. I can
>   set and see the 'g' in ethtool, and
>   the LEDs adjacent to the built-in
>   Ethernet connector stay on when the
>   machine is is in suspend mode.
>   Pressing the power button in suspend
>   mode wakes up the machine (about five
>   seconds to the Ubuntu splash screen;
>   no booting).
>
> (BTW, those Ethernet LEDs didn't stay
>   on when running 9.04.)
>
> I'm sending magic packets from my
>   Linux-based router machine (not
>   Ubuntu). If I'm logged into the 4550,
>   I can run tcpdump port 40000 (default
>   port for magic packets on the router
>   box), and I can see the magic packets;
>   I can dump them with tcpdump -xx -XX
>   too. But with all of the above
>   working, the 4550 won't wake on lan.
>
> What am I missing?
>
> Thanks in advance.

P.S. Merry Christmas and happy holidays everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the (paper and early PDF) manual states it has wol, their website was telling that too. so we ordered a few for the offices. when they arrived there was no wol, and after a year they removed the advertised  text about wol from the website and the PDF manuals.

as usual with dell their support had no clue what that even means and after several hours wasted (i think that is their plan, to give you a runaround and waste your time so you won't call them anymore) I gave up on this. Even PCI cards with wol won't work as it is not supported in the BIOS.

after that experience we ordered some HP's and they have a regular BIOS and yes, they have wol too as advertised.